# Convergence of the series $ \sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac {1}{n\log^2n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show that

$$ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac {1}{n\log^2n} $$

converges.

My work:

Since for n = 3 to infinity, the summands are positive, then we know that the sequence of partial sums,

$$S_N =  \sum_{n=3}^N \frac {1}{n\log^2n},$$

is monotonically increasing.

So, it remains to show that $S_N$ is bounded.

Can I get a tip on how to show the boundedness?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know about the integral test for convergence of a series?

Comment: Integral test with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x\log^2(x)}$ and using the substitution $u = \log(x) \implies \int f(x)dx = \int \frac{du}{u^2}$.

Comment: Hi @User, thanks so much for the hint - I will try it now.  I didn't think of it because I noticed that log^2 (on Wolfram Alpha) does not behave monotonically -- but then $log_e(3) > 1$, and since the series does start at 3, I can be sure that the summands are monotonically decreasing (to zero), so the test is applicable.

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint @Winther :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you can use the integral test.  Alternatively, you can use the Cauchy condensation test: if $a_n$ is non-negative and non-increasing,  then $$\sum a_n \mbox{  converges}\Leftrightarrow\sum 2^n a_{2^n} \mbox{  converges}$$ In your case, you get
$$\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}2^n\frac{1}{2^n(\ln{2^n})^2}=\frac{1}{\ln^2{2}}\sum_{n=3}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
which converges.

Comment: Very cool answer @Capublanca - thanks so much :-).

Comment: For completeness it is worth noting that the convergence equivalence  is true if $a_n$ is positive and non-increasing. Which it is here.

Comment: Thank you Simon! I've edited my answer.